# Find Text having highest density of words

Tags: c, ruby, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a hash as below:

```
{1=>[{content=>"Text of paragraph 1.........."},{content=>"Text of paragraph 2"}]}
```

The above hash is created after parsing a text file . The key "1" represents page 1. It points to an array of hashes , each hash pointing to a paragraph with content key pointing to actual text.

Now I have a word list like [word1,word2,word3]. I have to iterate through all the paragraph content of that page and tell which paragraph has the most occurrence of these words.

I can write my own code where I do regex match for each of the word against the paragraph . But I wanted to know if there is any powerful string matching library that can solve this use case (in C, C++, or even ruby)

Its just not string matching. I need a library that can extract the data that consists the highest density for the words in the word list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, in `ruby`, for counting the frequency of words in a string:

```
def count_words(string)
  string
    .scan(/[\w']+/) # Treat strings like "don't" as a single word
    .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |w,h|
      h[w.downcase] += 1
    end
end
```

Usage:

```
word_occurrences = count_words("Hello world! Hello, vipul.")
  => {"hello"=>2, "world"=>1, "vipul"=>1}
```

You shouldn't need a third party library to implement something this simple.

To check occurrences of a specific word, just look it up in the hash:

```
word_occurrences[word1.downcase]
```

To obtain a list of the "highest density" words, just sort by hash value:

```
word_occurrences.sort_by {|_word, occurrences| -occurrences}
# Note the negative to make this descending, not ascending
```

Comment: The only reason I might consider using a third party library is if a simple regex like `/[\w']+/` is insufficient for your needs. It would be virtually impossible to write a *perfect* regex to separate words - but you could instead use a Natural Language Parser. (However, I strongly suspect that this is overkill for what you are trying to achieve...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in my case, the word list will be around 100-200 and the text can be as big as 4-5 page content. I was looking for a different solution which could be scalable and have least performance issues.

Comment: The above solution is only a guideline. Feel free to integrate a database or something if performance becomes an issue... But to be honest, 100-200 words across 5 pages is hardly going to be an issue! If you were dealing with *millions* of pages, then you'd have more cause for concern.